# CloudBuild Trigger with service account using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-build, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-iam

I try to create a `CloudBuild Trigger` running as a service account and not the standard `Cloud Build` service account.

My terraform code is running using service account impersonation with the following service account:

```
resource "google_service_account" "terraform" {
  account_id   = "terraform"
  description  = "SA to run terraform command"
  display_name = "terraform"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "terraform" {
  project  = "XXX"
  for_each = toset([
    "roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageAdmin",
    "roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin",
    "roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin",
    "roles/source.admin",
    "roles/storage.admin",
    "roles/cloudbuild.builds.editor",
  ])
  role   = each.value
  member = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.terraform.email}"
}
```

Then I just used the example provided by Terraform but I get an error message

```
google_cloudbuild_trigger.service-account-trigger: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Error creating Trigger: googleapi: Error 403: generic::permission_denied: user does not have impersonation permission on the trigger service account specified: projects/XXX/serviceAccounts/cloud-sa@XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Example from [Terraform website](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudbuild_trigger#example-usage---cloudbuild-trigger-service-account)

```
data "google_project" "project" {}

resource "google_cloudbuild_trigger" "service-account-trigger" {
  trigger_template {
    branch_name = "main"
    repo_name   = "my-repo"
  }

  service_account = google_service_account.cloudbuild_service_account.id
  filename        = "cloudbuild.yaml"
  depends_on = [
    google_project_iam_member.act_as,
    google_project_iam_member.logs_writer
  ]
}

resource "google_service_account" "cloudbuild_service_account" {
  account_id = "cloud-sa"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "act_as" {
  project = data.google_project.project.project_id
  role    = "roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.cloudbuild_service_account.email}"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "logs_writer" {
  project = data.google_project.project.project_id
  role    = "roles/logging.logWriter"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.cloudbuild_service_account.email}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting the error message you shared, I understand that the user executing this action doesn't have impersonation permission on the service account you defined.

Reading through the article about [configuring user-specified service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-user-specified-service-accounts), there's a section detailing the [required IAM permissions](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-user-specified-service-accounts#permissions) to start builds using your specified service account. You will need to grant yourself the [Service Accout User](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#service-accounts-roles) in the project that hosts the service account.

I hope this information could help you :)